# evoking binary excecutable in a C++ project

Tags: c++

I have a main project to carry out some control tasks which involve the processing provided by 
some binary executables progA.exe, progB.exe, progC.exe. The bad disadvantage is I don't have the source codes of these progX.exe nor their libraries except binary executables

Is there any way that I can write the main project to prepare some input data, evoking & feed input data to progX.exe and further process their output? Is there such a coding project?

I don't know if this is a possible idea or not

Comment: Bad disadvantage? What are the good disadvantages, if I may ask?

Comment: Read about the `system` function. Or depending on platform [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), or [`fork`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fork.html) and [`exec`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/exec.html).

Comment: What you mean by "project"? If that is "build script" then the answer is "yes", it is quite usual to run various tools during build.

Comment: @Tiib: I mean C++ project since the processing in the main project is not simple (uses several OpenCV processing)

Comment: @KerrekSB: I meant to carry out some of my main tasks, at least I have the processing available in the executables, but not in the form of library calls nor source-code to recompile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is great documentation in MSDN about creating processes and redirecting input/output: [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Love that article, the number of times it has undergone editing on the MSDN site (just look at the comment history) is borderline laughable.

Comment: @WhozCraig: looks like there have been several problems with this solution and it's risky to take in :D